# Perl: find "pure perl" modules only

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm looking for a directory of perl modules which are **perl only**. That means (in DSLIP speak):

*Perl-only, no compiler needed, should be platform independent*

As far as I see the well known search engines does not allow to search in this category only. Am I wrong? Maybe there is a nice way to get a complete module list...?

Comment: A list of all pure perl modules on CPAN would be perfectly fine. Looking for "pure perl" does not helped so far.

Comment: What is the requirement for pure perl modules?  If needed you can add XS modules to your perl build and compile when you compile perl

Comment: In my working environment I'm not an admin - so I can't install XS modules by myself. Unfortunately our IT department is unwilling to install new modules. So my only chance to take advantage of CPAN is to use pure perl modules. That's why I'm looking for such a list: for better research and for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

http://deps.cpantesters.org/ shows whether a module is not pure-perl. The criteria are explained in [*A Brief Note on Purity warnings*](http://deps.cpantesters.org/static/purity.html), the source implementing this is somewhere in http://www.cantrell.org.uk/cgit/cgit.cgi/cpandeps/.

Combine this with [visitcpan](http://p3rl.org/visitcpan) to get data for every distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Unfortunately that identification if pure Perl or not does not work very well. It told me for example that _Date::Pcalc_ and _List::MoreUtils_ are not pure Perl. As far as I know they are.

Comment: You're mistaken. http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.30/MoreUtils.xs http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/STBEY/Date-Pcalc-6.1/src/C_XS/Pcalc.xs

Comment: Modules like List::MoreUtils have both a Pure Perl and an XS version in the same distribution so can not be reliably detected by that method.  You will only get the only pure perl modules.

Comment: Yes - I use the modules as Pure Perl and didn't realize that there is a XS version too.